# Auto connect vertices having coordinates

Tags: simplegraph

It is possible to let simplegraph calculate or create edges between vertices which have coordinates (ex. lat/lon) and same property (ex. linenumber=2550), so that from one vertex the nearest other vertex with same linenumber property will be connected.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more e.g. by supplying some source code /data? You also might want to file an issue at https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/issues

Comment: https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/issues/19 now has the issue

Comment: thank you very much. I haven't the time to programming every time I want, and I ask the question because I didn't know whether there has been such a functionality in SimpleGraph. But I have made also my own thoughts. I think there is a partly way with Gremlin using the choose operator to make first a list with the needed line numbers and then call a functionality called sweep algorithm from the Geo information scientific.